# Getting value using key in dictionary in python not working

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary in python as follows.

```
path_definition = {
       '00:00:00:00:00:01':'00:00:00:00:00:04',
       '00:00:00:00:00:02':'00:00:00:00:00:05',
       '00:00:00:00:00:03':'00:00:00:00:00:06',
};
```

If I do

```
for key in path_definition.keys()
      print('value {}'.format(path_definition[key])
```

It doesn't seem to work for some reason.

Comment: Is it because of your two syntax errors?

Comment: Which version of python are you using?, adding `:` and a `)`, the code works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
path_definition = {
       '00:00:00:00:00:01':'00:00:00:00:00:04',
       '00:00:00:00:00:02':'00:00:00:00:00:05',
       '00:00:00:00:00:03':'00:00:00:00:00:06' #comma not required
} #Semicolon not required


for key in path_definition.keys(): #semicolon missing
      print('value {}'.format(path_definition[key])) #extra parentheses missing
```

Answer (score 2):

Your for is wrong, try this:

```
for key in path_definition.keys():  #colon is missed
  print('value {}'.format(path_definition[key])) #a parenthesys is missed
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not mentioned in your question, what error you are seeing (if at all), I see two issues with your code right now:

1. You are missing a `:` at the end of the `for` statement.
2. You are missing a `)` at the end of the `print` statement.

Fixing those:

```
>>> for key in path_definition.keys():
...     print('value {}'.format(path_definition[key]))
...
value 00:00:00:00:00:06
value 00:00:00:00:00:05
value 00:00:00:00:00:04
```